# how to draw n horizontal y-axis parallel lines intersect m vertical x-axis parallel lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, tikz-path, tikz-calc

### use \foreach command add node circle

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \draw[->] (-10, 0) -- (10, 0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, -10) -- (0, 10) node[above] {$y$};
 {
  \foreach \n in {8,7,...,-8}
  \draw[name path global=a,domain=-8:8,smooth, variable=\y, blue] plot ({\y}, {\n});
 { \foreach \n in {8,7,...,-8}
  \draw[name path global=b,rotate=90,domain=-8:8,smooth, variable=\y, green] plot ({\y}, {\n});

  \draw[name intersections={of={a} and {b}}](intersection-1) circle (1pt);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you want, for instance with a quick picture?

Comment: @NBur -I'm sorry，Look at it again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of what you need. If it's something like your picture, but with x,y axes, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \draw[blue,very thin] (-8.5,-8.5) grid (8.5,8.5);
  \draw[thick,->] (-10, 0) -- (10, 0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0, -10) -- (0, 10) node[above] {$y$}; 
  \foreach \x in {-8,...,8} \foreach \y in {-8,...,8}
    \draw[blue,very thin,fill=white] (\x,\y) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the two colors for the grid, as in @Juan's answer, I'll use the grid.
Here are the variants.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xmin{-8}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xmax{8}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ymin{-8}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ymax{8}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
    \pgfsetlayers{main,foreground layer}
    \begin{scope}
    \draw[->] (\xmin-2, 0) -- (\xmax+2, 0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0, \ymin-2) -- (0, \ymax+2) node[above] {$y$};
    
    \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,\xmax}{
        \draw [blue] (\x, \ymin) -- (\x, \ymax);
    }
    \foreach \y in {\ymin,...,\ymax}{
        \draw [green] (\xmin, \y) -- (\xmax, \y);
    }
    \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,\xmax}{
        \foreach \y in {\ymin,...,\ymax}{
            \fill[red] (\x,\y) circle [radius=2pt];
    }}
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=22cm]
    \draw[->] (\xmin-2, 0) -- (\xmax+2, 0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0, \ymin-2) -- (0, \ymax+2) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[step=1cm,blue,very thin] (\xmin, \ymin) grid (\xmax, \ymax);
    \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,\xmax}{
        \foreach \y in {\ymin,...,\ymax}{
            \fill[red] (\x,\y) circle [radius=2pt];
    }}
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=44cm]
    
    \draw[->] (\xmin-2, 0) -- (\xmax+2, 0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0, \ymin-2) -- (0, \ymax+2) node[above] {$y$};
    
    \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,\xmax}{
        \draw[name path=a, blue] (\x, \ymin) -- (\x, \ymax);
        \foreach \y in {\ymin,...,\ymax}{
            \draw[name path=b, green] (\xmin,\y) -- (\xmax,\y);
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}
            \fill[name intersections={of=a and b}, red](intersection-1) circle (2pt);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
    }
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: -thank you so much